# Inserting data from another class into CURL

Tags: php, class, curl, header

I have two class; APIKey and Curl. I can not put the API Key in the header line of the CURL class.

I am trying to add this API Key to the Curl Class.

```
$this->apiValue
```

I have work the examples and tried to try them but I have not been successful.

I get Internal 500 error. What could be the problem?

Code:

```
class APIkey
 {
      public $apiValue;

      public function __construct(string $apiValue)
      {
          $this->apiValue = $apiValue;
      }

      public function getApiAna()
      {
                echo $this->apiValue;
      }
}
```

Result:

> Internal 500 Error

Comment: You should check your error logs, and turn on debugging. There's almost certainly some information available to you somewhere that will tell you quite clearly what's going wrong.

Comment: I got these lines in the error log; [LINK](https://pastebin.com/TeyiGN8L) - Line 34: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Auth-Key: Bearer '. $this->apiValue));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to implement inheritance but not using as expected.
Also calling non-static method as static.
Use like this:

```
$c = new Curl('8fbb80d7f378f2276246388093439422');
$c->lists($json, $http_status);
```

Comment: I made changes but I still get the same error (500).

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Your code worked. Thank you for your time!